# Non-semisimple Lie algebra tensors

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{L}$ be a *non*-semisimple Lie algebra. Let $T_i$ be its generators. As usual, define the structure constants $C_{ij}^k$ by $[T_i,T_j]=C_{ij}^kT_k$ and the metric tensor $g_{jm}$ by $g_{jm}=C_{ij}^kC_{km}^i$ (Einstein sum convention for repeated indices). Define $S_{ijm}=C_{ij}^kg_{km}$.
You have now two kinds of $\mathfrak{L}$: the "bad" ($S_{ijm}$ vanishes identically, e.g. for $\mathfrak{L=aff_1}$) and the "ugly", where $S_{ijm}$ doesn't vanish (e.g. the 4-dimensional Lie algebra defined by $[T_i,T_j]=(T_k-T_l)\epsilon_{ijkl}$, where $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita symbol).
Is there an easy way to define the difference between "bad" and "ugly" by "standard" Lie algebra properties (nilpotent, reductive, solvable, Kac-Moody etc. etc.)?

Comment: Your question is unclear because some things are not defined: $g_{ij}$, $g^i_j$, $C^{ijk}$,… it would help if you clearly distinguished what is a result and what is a definition.

Comment: I am still confused by this question, especially by the upper/lower index convention.  Abstract Lie algebras do not have anything like "complex conjugate transpose".  Hence condition 1 is still unclear to me.  (continued below)

Comment: As for condition 2, notice that your $g_{ij}$ is proportional to the Killing form and hence since your Lie algebra is non-semisimple, Cartan's semisimplicity criterion says that it is degenerate.  Nonetheless it is still ad-invariant, whence condition 2 is true for all Lie algebras, assuming that $C_{ijk}$ are obtained from $C_k^{ij}$ by contracting with $g_{ij}$.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with Lie algebras, but obviously e.g. $C_{ijk}$ is identically zero for aff1 (because of dimension 2). Do you include this degenerate possibility in your statement? (Do such Lie algebras have a special name?)

Comment: Also: If you start with the tensor $C^i_{jk}$ and you can NOT invert $g_{lm}$ to get "the indices up", how do you arrive at $g^{no}$ at all? (I'm always working with matrix generators, thus my "complex conjugate transpose").